# Refresh data in TabView tabs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I recently started with `SwiftUI` and it gives me troubles. I'm stuck in part where I need to refresh data in particular `View` attached to `TabView`.

Explanation: I have 4 tabs in app and in one tab you can search for product and click save and in another you can check saved products.

***I'm using `Realm` for saving and saving works! Why? Because if I refresh the app I will see my product. But the problem is: if I save the product and then click on save tab, the product I just saved is not shown***.

So I don't know how can I refresh data in particular tab after tabs are initialised. This is the code of `TabView`:

```
  TabView {

        NoSavedView()
            .tabItem{
                Image("scanBottom")
                Text("Scan")
                    .foregroundColor(ColorsStatic.redish)
                    .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 12))

        }.tag(0)


        NoSearchView()
            .tabItem{
                Image("searchBottom")
                Text("Search")
                    .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(ColorsStatic.white)
        }.tag(1)

        NoHistoryView()
            .tabItem{
                Image("historyBottom")

                Text("History")
                    .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(ColorsStatic.white)
        }.tag(2)

        NoSavedView()
            .tabItem{
                Image("savedBottom")

                Text("Saved")
                    .font(.custom("Poppins-Medium", size: 12))
                    .foregroundColor(ColorsStatic.white)
        }.tag(3)


    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

I tried with refreshing data (re-fetch from `Realm`: `historiesViewModel.getHistories()`)  in `onAppear` function but app crashes due the `NSinternalInconsistencyException`.

I'm using `ObservableObject` and `ObservedObject`

Comment: Which view has the data?  can you attach the code for that view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any database framework, the important way of using SwiftUI and Combine framework is in `ObservableObject` and how `@EnvironmentObject` works.

1) Build your `ObservableObject`

```
class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published searchList: [SearchItemModel] = []
    @Published savedList: [SearchItemModel] = []
}
```

see that `@Published`, it will tell all the listener in the event this list get updated.

2) Add `@EnvironmentObject` in your TabView

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
    TabView {
...
}
```

here I named my view `ContentView`, a view that have a `TabView` in it.

3) Populate the `UserData`

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(UserData())
```

4) Create a search list view and saved list view

```
struct SearchListView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
    List {
...
}

struct SavedListView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
    List {
...
}
```

here you see that `SearchListView` and `SavedListView` each one have their own `@EnvironmentObject`.

Do we need to send our `userData` object from `ContentView` to them? The answer is no.

The way `@EnvironmentObject` work is automated pass by reference to child view which have the same `@EnvironmentObject` declared in them.

```
ContentView.userData == SearchListView.userData == SavedListView.userData
```

because

```
ContentView.userData
|
TabView
|                \
SearchListView   SavedListView
```

5) Update the list in `UserData`

All we need now is to update the `savedList` in `userData` from the `SearchListView` and the `SavedListView` will be automatically updated.

```
ForEach(userData.searchList) { item in
            ListView(item: item)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.userData.savedList.append(item)
                }
```

I suggest you to follow this tutorial from apple to become more familiar with SwiftUI and Combine

- [Building list](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation)
- [Combine and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)

After that, you can combine it with any database framework you want.